# How to trim the last matching string using regexp_substr

Tags: regexp-substr

I am trying to use regexp_substr to retrieve string within [!< & >!].  I have below statement but it returned ' To test with regexp_substr.>!]'.  How can I exclude >!] and return just the string?

select regexp_substr('[!< To test with regexp_substr.>!]','[^[!<]+>!]') from dual

Answer (score 0):

This method groups everything that is between your start and end character sequences (assuming at least 1 character will be there), then returns just that group of characters.  The square brackets need to be escaped so the regex engine does not think you are referring to a character class.  Note your example has a space in front of the first letter, which is preserved in the output:

```
select regexp_substr('[!< To test with regexp_substr.>!]','\[!<(.+)>!\]', 1, 1, 'i', 1) from dual;


STRING_EXAMPLE              
----------------------------
 To test with regexp_substr.
```